# Allowing inbound traffic from a different AWS security group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect my server to a mongodb instance (they are in the same region).
In the mongodb's security group, when allowing inbound traffic from 0.0.0.0/0, the server manages to connect. When restricting the inbound traffic to the security group of the server, it can't connect.
Also, if I restrict the inbound traffic to the IP of the server, it connects again...

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the server's external IP/DNS rather than its EC2 internal one.

Comment: I'm using the server's security group id and not the ip

Comment: I'm not talking about the security group settings, I'm talking about in your code when you put in the IP/DNS of the mongodb server.